# Tomcat JDBC pool configuration

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, tomcat8, ojdbc

I am facing an odd issue in some of environments of UAT and PROD, but not in SIT. It seems to be a configuration related issue to me. Though all the settings, configuration verified are same.

Getting 'Closed Statement: next' SQLException while trying to loop over a result set with a `while (rs.next())`.

Code snippet, error stack trace, version details are provided below.

Existing code:

```
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
private boolean fetchAndInsertData(final String indexType, final IndexWriter indexWriter) throws Exception {

    logger.info("Entering fetchAndInsertData()");

    Transaction tx = null;
    boolean success = false;
    CallableStatement callstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        tx = this.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

        callstmt = this.getCurrentSession().connection().prepareCall("{call GET_VAL_PROC(?,?)}");
        callstmt.setString(1, indexType);
        callstmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);

        callstmt.execute();

        rs = (ResultSet) callstmt.getObject(2);
        rs.setFetchSize(5000);

        logger.info("Resultset:"+ rs);

        while (rs.next()) {
            indexWriter.addDocument(convertResultToDoc(rs));
        }
        success = true;

    }  catch(SQLException e){
        logger.error("Error in SQL execute", e);
        success = false;
        tx.commit();
        return success;
     } catch (final Exception e) {
        logger.error("Getting Exception", e);            
        success = false;
    } finally {
        tx.commit();
    }
    logger.info("Exiting fetchAndInsertData()");
    return success;
}

private Document convertResultToDoc(ResultSet results) throws SQLException {
    final Document doc = new Document();
    final String resultKey = results.getString(1) != null ? results.getString(1).toString() : null;
    final String resultValue = results.getString(2) != null ? results.getString(2).toString() : null;
    doc.add(new TextField("resultKey", resultKey, Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("resultValue", resultValue, Field.Store.YES));
    return doc;
}
```

Error stack trace:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: Closed Statement: next
    at 
    oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at 
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
    at 
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
    at 
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:271)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:205)
    at com.ville.dao.SomeDaoImpl.fetchAndInsertData(SomeDaoImpl.java:263)
    at com.ville.dao.SomeDaoImpl.createIndex(SomeDaoImpl.java:227)
    at com.ville.dao.SomeDaoImpl.getDetails(SomeDaoImpl.java:375)
    at com.ville.service.ServiceImpl.serviceCreateIndex(ServiceImpl.java:32)
    at com.ville.service.WSControl.controlCreateIndex(WSControl.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.ville.filter.MultiRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(MultiRequestWrapperFilter.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.ville.filter.HttpInterceptorFilter.doFilter(HttpInterceptorFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1103)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1477)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2018-07-13 07:02:56 INFO  [http-nio-21290-exec-3] SomeDaoImpl - Exiting SomeDaoImpl.fetchAndInsertData()
2018-07-13 07:02:56 ERROR [http-nio-21290-exec-3] GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler - RestError [status=500, id=-1, message=Transaction not successfully started, developerMessage=org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:127)
    at com.ville.dao.SomeDaoImpl.fetchAndInsertData(SomeDaoImpl.java:281)
    at com.ville.dao.SomeDaoImpl.createIndex(SomeDaoImpl.java:227)
    at com.ville.dao.SomeDaoImpl.getDetails(SomeDaoImpl.java:375)
    at com.ville.service.ServiceImpl.serviceCreateIndex(ServiceImpl.java:32)
    at com.ville.service.WSControl.controlCreateIndex(WSControl.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.ville.filter.MultiRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(MultiRequestWrapperFilter.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.ville.filter.HttpInterceptorFilter.doFilter(HttpInterceptorFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1103)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1477)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Version details:

Tomcat Version: 8.0.18_1
JRE : 1.8.0_111l64
OJDBC6.jar with JDBC : 11.1.0.7.0-Production
Oracle DB Version: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Existing config in context.xml

```
Resource name="jdbc/SomeDS"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@DbUrlWithPortNameEtc"
username="***"
password="********"
connectionProperties="SetBigStringTryClob=true"
accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true"
maxTotal="30"
maxIdle="10"
initialSize="5"
maxWaitMillis="180000"
```

Comment: the method that throws the exception is `com.ville.dao.SomeDaoImpl.fetchAndInsertData(SomeDaoImpl.java:263)` not `fetchAndInsert`

Comment: Thanks Fran. The actual method name is "fetchAndInsertData". I had made a typo with the method name. Corrected it.

Comment: Is `convertResultToDoc` being executed any time? Maybe you are simply getting to the end of the cursor?

Comment: also you could execute `tx.commit();`twice if `SQLException` is catched

Comment: The error could suggest your connection management is incorrect and connections are used concurrently or closed sooner than you think, leading to statements and result sets being closed prematurely.

Comment: Also, I'd expect to see `tx.rollback();` in the catch block rather than `tx.commit()`

Comment: @FranMontero Yes Fran, convertResultToDoc is executing. The ResultSet contains data. I'll try with your suggestion about commit(). Thanks :)

Comment: Yes @MarkRotteveel, I understand your point. Googled for TOMCAT JDBC POOL configuration, tried with suggested configs but nothing is working. 
I tried with below settings in addition with the mentioned ones:
`
    validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
    validationInterval="600000"
    testWhileIdle="true"
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="1800000"
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="180000"
`

Comment: callstmt = this.getCurrentSession().connection()... this is code smell, are you sure you are not running this more than once ? or maybe something else closed your session/connection... i can see from the stack-trace you are using Spring, just ask for data source, don't go to the connection level, let framework do its job...

Comment: Also, you're mixing `Hibernate` with plain `JDBC`, which is normally not recommended. However, when you need to use plain JDBC (Hibernate doesn't support everything), it's recommended that you get a `Connection` object via the `Session.doWork` method and not the way you did it.

Comment: How many times does the loop actually execute? Maybe zero? Maybe you are fetching an already-closed `ResultSet`.

Comment: Regarding DB_URL, you are using TNS alias. Are you passing the  system property TNS_ADMIN (-Doracle.net.tns_admin=<path where tnsnames.ora exist>) ? I would suggest you to provide the full URL with hostname, port number etc.,